# C# how can I select all the text in a textbox when I double click?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Using C# how can I select all the text in a textbox when I double click? My text contains spaces "This is a test", when I double click by default only one word is highlighted, how can I highlight all the text?

What I am trying to achieve is a quick way for users to clear the texbox of text, the text exceeds the length of the box so you can't select the end and drag back to delete, you have to click and use the backspace and delete keys to clear the text.

Thanks
Alison

Comment: Common "solution" is having it all selected (see Ardman answer) in the OnFocus event.. double clicking to select all text is not very common so your users won't know it exists.

Comment: You may also consider selecting all of the text in the textbox when it receives focus (either with the tab key or a mouse click, like the address bar in a web browser—see the `OnFocus` event for the textbox). This would still provide a quick way to delete the text without losing what many users would consider the default behavior of being able to double-click to select a word.

Comment: it might also be useful to teach your users about `Ctrl+a`, or make the TextBox's text wrap (might not be possible due to design / screen real estate issues)

Comment: @vlad: Oh, the things I wish I could teach users... :-)

Comment: @Cody Gray I'm only bringing it up because I had a similar issue this very morning..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.SelectAll();
```

The TextBox has a `SelectAll` method which you can use.  Add it in your double click event handler.

Answer (score 4):

try something like this. When the MouseDoubleClick-Event is fired...

```
myTextBox.SelectAll();
```

Just check the MSDN --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectall.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Triple clicks could select the whole paragraph. If you change the behavior of double click, word selection could be a little hard.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a [DoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick.aspx) event handler to the textbox and then call the [SelectAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectall.aspx) method

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are talking WindowsForms, then all you have to do is attach an EventHandler to the DoubleClick event and invoke SelectAll

```
private void sampleTextBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  sampleTextBox.SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: You could do instead:   ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll(); ... which is a bit neater

Answer (score 1):

The textbox control exposes the SelectionStart and Selection Length properties.

You just need to simply wire the double click event of the textbox to set those properties.

SelectionStart will be 0.
SelectionLength will be the length of the text (easily determined by the Text property).

On edit:
The above solution to use SelectAll() is much easier.

Comment: Bit overkill when there is a SelectAll method.

Comment: Indeed.  I remember SelectionStart & Length from some code where I needed to highlight a portion of the text.  Didn't even realize there was a far far far easier solution.  That is what intellisense is for.